# Ubuntu 15.04 is slow after startup

Tags: 15.04, system

In my laptop I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 and it's core i3, but the system is slow even when I open firefox, chrome and webStorm. RAM is 4Gb.

[image: system moniter]

Sometimes cpu1 and cpu2 usages are getting higher..

What can I do????

Comment: Ypu RAM is almost full and you are swapping. I do not know what webStorm is (never heard before), but you are clearly running low on RAM. Try to look in the "Processes" tab what is eating it up so much and kill it.

Comment: @david foerster done

Answer (score 1):

Ypu RAM is almost full and you are swapping. I do not know what webStorm is (never heard before), but you are clearly running low on RAM. Try to look in the "Processes" tab what is eating it up so much and kill it.